# Proving that universe is a blackbody

Tags: thermodynamics, cosmology, thermal-radiation, cosmic-microwave-background

How can you theoretically explain why cosmic microwave background seems to be coming from a perfect blackbody given that the universe is no longer at thermal equilibrium?

Comment: You do know that the CMB was emitted a long time ago, right?

Comment: Yes, indeed. But my doubt is that, how can we explain the fact that CMB fits with a black body spectrum given that universe's expansion is affecting the wavelength of the CMB.

Comment: You redshift a black body, still a black body

Comment: You need to [edit] that info into your question, and explain why you believe that the expansion would lead to a distortion of the spectrum.

Comment: @Thomas. Your point sounds interesting. Still, for applying the wein's displacement law, we need the temp of the system to be constant but the universe is not so. Any suggestions?

Comment: Sorry, I'm adding a question for the first time here. My intuition says that CMB would depend on the temp of its local environment, not on the temp of the whole universe.

Comment: What do you think the temperature of the universe is then? And the local environment?

Comment: @KV18 In the early stage of the universe, just after the "recombination epoch" the universe was pretty homogeneous but as of now, we've a wide range of temperature in the universe. We can't apply Wien's displacement law in the first place (my opinion).

Comment: There is no wide range of temperatures. In deep space, the temperature is still 2.7 K. It is a near perfect black body.

Comment: @KV18. Yeah. In deep space, your point is correct but in stars and Black holes, the temp is very high compared to 2.7K. We're ignoring it. There's my doubt.

Comment: When we measure the temperature of the sun we are applying a black body formula.

Comment: This is concise : http://planck.cf.ac.uk/science/cmb . The black body radiation of stars will be bumps at much higher frequencies than the cmb at each specific angle